# Why is this line causing leaks?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

The following is causing leaks (identified via the Leaks instrument):

```
field = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2); 
NSString *column3 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field]]; (this line here) 
rowDefinitionA = column3;
[column3 release];
```

Is there anything wrong with that line specifically?

Comment: FWIW, do you realize it is easier to write `NSString *column3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:field];` and get the same autoreleased string?

Comment: IIRC, Leaks will tell you where the leaked object is being created, not where it's being leaked. It looks like you're handling column3 correctly, but what are you doing with rowDefinitionA, which references the leaked object?

Answer (score 1):

You're actually over-releasing `column3`. Either lose the `autorelease` or `[column3 release]`.

Comment: Sorry, I copied that code from a test I was doing.  Autorelease isn't there anymore, but it still causes a leak.